# Working with socat to send a message and receive a response

Tags: socat

Using Socat on my server I have the current command:

`socat -u tcp-l:7767,fork system:/app/getmsg.sh`

All getmsgh.sh does is:

```
read MESSAGE
echo $MESSAGE
```

I'm trying to figure out a way for the client to send a message and receive the output of getmsg.sh

Trying on the client:

```
echo "hello" | socat -t 30 tcp:localhost:7767 -
```

Does not seem to work. It shows up on the server but not on the client. It seems that if you try to pass a message with the client socat wants to exit immediately

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the `-u` option on the server side. The meaning of the `-u` option from the `socat` man page:

> Uses unidirectional mode. The first address  is  only  used  for reading,  and the second address is only used for writing

Hence, the `tcp-l:` side is only read from and the `system:` side is only written to, instead of a bi-directonal connection (which is the default). Removing the `-u` option makes the example in the question work.